# Locally disable warnings of Python Language Server in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-language-server

I have recently installed Python Language Server in Visual Studio Code.

I sometimes have some warnings that I want to locally disabled

For example, let's assume I have the following code:

```
import org.sikuli.script.SikulixForJython
from sikuli.Sikuli import *
from guide import *
```

It is normally run from Sikulix, which uses Jython libraries. Since my favorite editor cannot load this module, it would raise a warning:
`unresolved import 'org.sikuli.script.SikulixForJython'      Python(unresolved-import)`

With `pylint`, I can disable that warning for only these 3 lines with something like:

```py
# pylint: disable=unresolved-import
import org.sikuli.script.SikulixForJython
from sikuli.Sikuli import *
from guide import *
# pylint: enable=unresolved-import
```

How to do something similar with Python Language Server?

Thanks

Comment: An alternative is to disable warning globally via the settings `"python.analysis.disabled": ["too-many-function-arguments", "parameter-missing"],` but I am looking for a local solution (i.e. class, function, conditional block)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently no support for per-line warning suppression. To request such a feature, please open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server.

Comment: I had already requested the feature. Such query was related to an issue that already existed: https://github.com/Microsoft/python-language-server/issues/264

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of settings in vscode:

- Global: `settings.json`. This can be reached using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and on the top right panel, clicking on the brackets icon (Open settings (JSON)).
- Local: `${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/settings.json`

So what you should do is just creating file `${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/settings.json` and adding line `"python.analysis.disabled": ["too-many-function-arguments", "parameter-missing"],` to it.

Comment: A short tip: There's no need to create the file yourself. After opening `Settings`, first click on the link `Workspace Settings` (at the top). If you now click on the curly brackets in the upper right, VSCode will automatically create (or open an existing) `settings.json` for the current workspace  ;-)

Comment: That is a first step to do what I want. However, I would like to keep the warning for the other `import` (so basically disabling the warning just for 3 lines). I have updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a partial implementation of linting disabling (for all warnings/errors of a single line).

You can use the keyword `# noqa` to disable the warning, as tracked in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/python-language-server/issues/264

The code updated to disable warnings from Pylan would then be:

```py
import org.sikuli.script.SikulixForJython  # noqa
from sikuli.Sikuli import *  # noqa
from guide import *  # noqa
```